# How to convert binary string to a byte?

Tags: java

there is a string fill with 0 and 1,like `String s = "10000000"`, which length is 8.And how can i transform it to a byte.such as "10000000"===>-128.
I try to use `Byte.parseByte(s, 2)`,but get the error "Value out of range. Value:"10000000" Radix:2".So,how can i solve it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883428/java-convert-binary-string-to-int , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649348 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530015/java-converting-string-of-binary-digits-to-decimal-number-using-recursion?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032458 - although if it's homework..

Comment: Did you try using Integer.parseInt(s,2) ? The value you are using is out of bounds for Byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse it as an `Integer` and then cast it to byte:

```
...
String s = "10000000";
int val = Integer.parseInt(s, 2);
byte b = (byte) val;
System.err.println(b);
...
```

Output:

```
-128
```

Comment: thank you very much